# Is it possible to free dynamic allocated memory inside the scope of a function with a return value of a pointer after a return statement in C?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra, gcc-warning

To simplify my question is the following code free of unidentified behavior and violations of good C programming practices ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *get_column(size_t dimension, double matrix[dimension][dimension], unsigned int columnIndex)
{
    double *column = malloc(dimension * sizeof(double));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)    column[i] = matrix[i][columnIndex];
    return column;  
    free(column);
}
```

I declared a 3 x 3 matrix, used another locally declared function to display the resulted vector, and the GCC (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0 compiler  did not produce any errors or raise warnings, the program executed as expected.

```
void print_vector(size_t dimension, double vector[dimension])
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < dimension; i++)   printf("| %f |\n", vector[i]);
}

int main()
{
    double A[3][3] = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
                 };
        
    print_vector(3, get_columb(3, A, 2)); //another function that print an element per line
                         
                         
    
}
```

and produced the following output:

```
| 3.000000 |
| 6.000000 |
| 9.000000 |
```

By the way, I am a beginner at programming in general.

Comment: No, the `free(column);` is dead code and will not be reached.

Comment: @Got Tod – 
`get_columb`?

Comment: There won't be undefined behaviour, just a memory leak due to never freeing the allocated memory and thus not leaving a dangling pointer (the consequence of @mch).

Comment: @Got Tod, Minor: With `size_t dimension`, rather than 2 different types with `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)`, use one: `for (size_t i = 0; i < dimension; i++)`.  Also consider `size_t columnIndex`.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement returns *immediately*, no statements after it will be executed. And returning a pointer, or passing a pointer to a function, doesn't duplicate the memory the pointer is pointing to, so you can't free the memory before the `return` either.

Because you don't save the result of `get_column` you have no way of freeing the memory. The simple solution is of course to save the returned pointer in a variable, that you can pass to `free` once you are done with it.

Or you could create an array in the calling function, and pass it to the `get_column` function to fill:

```
double *get_column(size_t dimension, double matrix[dimension][dimension], unsigned int columnIndex, double column[static dimension])
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        column[i] = matrix[i][columnIndex];

    return column;
}

// ...

double column[3];
print_vector(3, get_column(3, A, 2, column));
```

Because it still returns the `column` it can still be used as part of other expressions. And since there's no dynamic allocation, there's nothing to free.

---

If it's a *requirement* to do the dynamic allocation inside the `get_column` function, then you really have no other choice than to save the returned pointer in a variable, and pass it to `free` later:

```
double *column = get_column(3, A, 2);
print_vector(3, column);
free(column);
```

Comment: I suggest replacing parameter `double *column` with `double column[static dimension]`

Comment: @tstanisl Good idea, I always forget about that syntax. :)

Comment: @tstanisl Any reason to not also suggest `double matrix[static dimension][static dimension]`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, `static` can only be used for the first dimension.

Comment: @tstanisl OK, so maybe `double matrix[static dimension][dimension]`?